# SOAP service возвращает пустой массив через WSDL вместо данных из базы.

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Пытаюсь написать SOAP сервер и обращаться к нему через SoapClient(WSDL mode).
Написал сервер на php, добавил WSDL файл.
Запрос отправляется через Соап клиент, но ответ всегда пустой.

Метод на сервере:

```
public function getCarMakes()
    {
        $carMakesArr = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars order by make";
        try
        {
            foreach($this->conn->query($sql) as $row)
            {
                $carMakesArr[] = array( $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

            return $carMakesArr;
    }
```

Мой ВСДЛ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is Metro/2.3.1-b419 (branches/2.3.1.x-7937; 2014-08-04T08:11:03+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.10-b140803.1500 JAXWS-API/2.2.11 JAXB-RI/2.2.10-b140802.1033 JAXB-API/2.2.12-b140109.1041 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://wsdl.example.org/" name="ServerWS" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:tns="http://wsdl.example.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://wsdl.example.org/" schemaLocation="ServerWS_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="buyCar">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:buyCar"/>
  </message>
  <message name="buyCarResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:buyCarResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarMakes">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarMakes"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarMakesResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarDetailsById">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarDetailsById"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarDetailsByIdResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarDetailsByIdResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="searchByParams">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByParams"/>
  </message>
  <message name="searchByParamsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByParamsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="ServerWS">
    <operation name="buyCar">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/buyCarRequest" message="tns:buyCar"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/buyCarResponse" message="tns:buyCarResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarMakes">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarMakesRequest" message="tns:getCarMakes"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarMakesResponse" message="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarDetailsById">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarDetailsByIdRequest" message="tns:getCarDetailsById"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarDetailsByIdResponse" message="tns:getCarDetailsByIdResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="searchByParams">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/searchByParamsRequest" message="tns:searchByParams"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/searchByParamsResponse" message="tns:searchByParamsResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="ServerWSPortBinding" type="tns:ServerWS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="buyCar">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarMakes">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarDetailsById">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="searchByParams">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="ServerWS">
    <port name="ServerWSPort" binding="tns:ServerWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/soap/server.php"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Моя XML схема:

```
 <xs:complexType name="getCarMakes">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id_array1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getCarMakesResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Мой запрос из Соап клиента:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/soap/ServerWS.wsdl',
                        array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
                              'trace' => 1,
                              'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2)
                             );

try
    {

        $arr = (array)$client->getCarMakes();

        echo "<b>First method:</b> <br>";

    }
    catch(SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $client->__getLastRequest();
    echo $client->__getLastResponse(); 
     var_dump($arr);
```

Возвращает пустой массив, хотя по логам запрос в базу происходит, но вот данные почему-то не возвращаются:

Запрос:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<env:envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl.example.org/">
<env:body><ns1:getcarmakes></ns1:getcarmakes>
   </env:body></env:envelope>
```

Ответ:

```
  <env:envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl.example.org/">
    <env:body><ns1:getcarmakesresponse></ns1:getcarmakesresponse>
    </env:body>
  </env:envelope>
```